# Are Func<T> parameters in constructor slowing down my IoC resolving?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, simple-injector

I'm trying to improve the performance of my IoC container. We are using Unity and SimpleInjector and we have a class with this constructor:

```
public AuditFacade(
    IIocContainer container, 
    Func<IAuditManager> auditManagerFactory,
    Func<ValidatorFactory> validatorCreatorFactory, 
    IUserContext userContext,
    Func<ITenantManager> tenantManagerFactory, 
    Func<IMonitoringComponent> monitoringComponentFactory)
    : base(container, auditManagerFactory, GlobalContext.CurrentTenant, 
          validatorCreatorFactory, userContext, tenantManagerFactory)
{
    _monitoringComponent = new Lazy<IMonitoringComponent>(monitoringComponentFactory);
}
```

I also have another class with this constructor:

```
public AuditTenantComponent(Func<IAuditTenantRepository> auditTenantRepository)
{
    _auditTenantRepository = new Lazy<IAuditTenantRepository>(auditTenantRepository);
}
```

I'm seeing that the second one gets resolved in 1 millisecond, most of the time, whereas the first one takes on average 50-60 milliseconds. I'm sure the reasoning for the slower one is because of the parameters, it has more parameters. But how can I improve the performance of this slower one? Is it the fact that we are using `Func<T>` as parameters? What can I change if it is causing the slowness?

Comment: What does your profiler say about where the hot spots are?  All of this ceremony doesn't come without a price.

Comment: What profiler are you talking about? I'm new to this.

Comment: A code profiler.  The thing that tells you where your code is spending most of its time.

Comment: It would not surprise me if it just takes longer for the container to resolve a constructor with more parameters.

Comment: Stop guessing and measure. I reckon that there's a 90% chance that the problem isn't what you think it is. Use a .net performance profiler to establish where exactly the code hotspot is and then, if it doesn't make sense, post another question. Any answers to this question can, at best, be speculative.

Comment: That `AuditFacade` is one big ugly code smell. Why do you need to inject `Func<T>` dependencies, and why are you passing that all to the base class? And why are you injecting a Service Locator (your `IIoCContainer`) into that class? And Simple Injector is very unlikely to be the cause of this delay. Might it be that there is some type in their that does too much? Remember that [injection constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/).

Comment: If you like, we can feedback on your design. If you like this, please add more code to the question that shows what both the `AuditFacade` and its base class are doing.

Comment: @Steven, I'm curious to know why you asked why we inject Func<T> dependencies. Can you tell me why this shouldn't be done? Maybe I need to tell my team.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is possibly a lot to improve on your current design. These improvements can be placed in five different categories, namely:

1. Possible abuse of base classes
2. Use of Service Locator anti-pattern
3. Use of Ambient Context anti-pattern
4. Leaky abstractions
5. Doing too much in injection constructors

### Possible abuse of base classes

The general consensus is that you should prefer [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Inheritance is often overused and often adds more complexity compared to using composition. With inheritance the derived class is strongly coupled to the base class implementation. I often see a base class being used as practical utility class containing all sorts of helper methods for cross-cutting concerns and other behavior that some of the derived classes may need.

An often better approach is to remove the base class all together and inject a service into the implementation (the `AuditFacade` class in your case) that exposed just the functionality that the service needs. Or in case of cross-cutting concerns, don't inject that behavior at all, but wrap the implementation with a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that extends the class'es behavior with cross-cutting concerns.

In your case, I think the complication is clearly happening, since 6 out of 7 injected dependencies are not used by the implementation, but are only passed on to the base class. In other words, those 6 dependencies are implementation details of the base class, while the implementation still is forced to know about them. By abstracting (part of) that base class behind a service, you can minimize the number of dependencies that `AuditFacade` needs to two dependencies: the `Func<IMonitoringComponent>` and the new abstraction. The implementation behind that abstraction will have 6 constructor dependencies, but the `AuditFacade` (and other implementations) are oblivious to that.

### Use of Service Locator anti-pattern

The `AuditFacade` depends on an `IIocContainer` abstraction and this is very like an implementation of the [Service Locator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern). [Service Locator should be considered an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) because:

> it hides a class' dependencies, causing run-time errors instead of
>   compile-time errors, as well as making the code more difficult to
>   maintain because it becomes unclear when you would be introducing a
>   breaking change.

There are always better alternatives to injecting your container or an abstraction over your container into application code. Do note that at some times you might want to inject the container into factory implementations, but at long as those are placed inside your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), there's no harm in that, since [Service Locator is about roles, not mechanics](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/).

### Use of Ambient Context anti-pattern

The static `GlobalContext.CurrentTenant` property is an implementation of the [Ambient Context](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/07/23/ambientcontext.aspx) anti-pattern. [Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/) and I write about this pattern in [our book](https://manning.com/seemann2):

> The problems with AMBIENT CONTEXT are related to the problems with SERVICE 
>    LOCATOR. The main problems are:
>
> - The DEPENDENCY is hidden.
> - Testing becomes more difficult.
> - It becomes very hard to change the DEPENDENCY based on its context. [paragraph 5.3.3]

The use in this case is really weird IMO, because you grab the current tenant from some static property from inside your constructor to pass it on to the base class. Why doesn't the base class call that property itself?

But no one should call that static property. The use of those static properties makes your code harder to read and maintain. It makes unit testing harder and since your code base will usually be littered with calls to such static, it becomes a hidden dependency; it has the same downsides as the use of Service Locator.

### Leaky abstractions

A [Leaky Abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) is a [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) violation, where the abstraction violates the second part of the principle, namely:

> B. Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on
>   abstractions.

Although `Lazy<T>` is not abstractions by itself (`Lazy<T>` is a concrete type), it can become leaky abstraction when used as constructor argument. For instance, if you are injecting an `Lazy<IMonitoringComponent>` instead of an `IMonitoringComponent` directly (which is what you are basically doing in your code), the new `Lazy<IMonitoringComponent>` dependency leaks implementation details. This `Lazy<IMonitoringComponent>` communicates to the consumer that the used `IMonitoringComponent` implementation is expensive or time consuming to create. But why should the consumer care about this?

But there are more problems with this. If at one point in time the used `IUserContext` implementation becomes costly to create, we must start to make sweeping changes throughout the application (a violation of the [Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)) because all `IUserContext` dependencies need to be changed to `Lazy<IUserContext>` and all consumers of that `IUserContext` must be changed to use `userContext.Value.` instead. And you'll have to change all your unit tests as well. And what happens if you forget to change one `IUserContext` reference to `Lazy<IUserContext>` or when you accidentally depend on `IUserContext` when you create a new class? You have a bug in your code, because at that point the user context implementation is created right away and this will cause a performance problem (this causes a problem, because that is the reason you are using `Lazy<T>` in the first place).

So why are we exactly making sweeping changes to our code base and polluting it with that extra layer of indirection? There is no reason for this. The fact that a dependency is costly to create is an ***implementation detail***. You should hide it behind an abstraction. Here's an example:

```
public class LazyMonitoringComponentProxy : IMonitoringComponent {
    private Lazy<IMonitoringComponent> component;

    public LazyMonitoringComponentProxy(Lazy<IMonitoringComponent> component) {
        this.component = component;
    }

    void IMonitoringComponent.MonitoringMethod(string someVar) {
        this.component.Value.MonitoringMethod(someVar);
    }
}
```

In this example we've hidden the `Lazy<IMonitoringComponent>` behind a [proxy class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern). This allows us to replace the original `IMonitoringComponent` implementation with this `LazyMonitoringComponentProxy` without having to make any change to the rest of the applicaiton. With Simple Injector, we can register this type as follows:

```
container.Register<IMonitoringComponent>(() => new LazyMonitoringComponentProxy(
    new Lazy<IMonitoringComponent>(container.GetInstance<CostlyMonitoringComp>));
```

And just as `Lazy<T>` can be abused as leaky abstraction, the same holds for `Func<T>`, especially when you're doing this for performance reasons. When applying DI correctly, there is most of the time no need to inject factory abstractions into your code such as `Func<T>`.

Do note that if you are injecting `Lazy<T>` and `Func<T>` all over the place, you are complicating your code base unneeded.

### Doing too much in injection constructors

But besides `Lazy<T>` and `Func<T>` being leaky abstractions, the fact that you need them a lot is an indication of a problem with your application, because [Injection Constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). If constructors take a long time to run, your constructors are doing too much. Constructor logic is often hard to test and if such constructor makes a call to the database or requests data from HttpContext, [verification of your object graphs](https://simpleinjector.org/howto#verify-the-containers-configuration) becomes much harder to the point that you might skip verification all together. Skipping verification of the object graph is a terrible thing to do, because this forces you to click through the complete application to find out whether or not your DI container is configured correctly.

I hope this gives you some ideas about improving the design of your classes.

Comment: Definitely clear that we still have lots to do to fix our application. We did some tests on Friday with empty classes that use Func<> in our ctors. We discovered some classes that do too much in the constructors. These points above will give us a starting point.

Comment: Hi @Steven, I saw someone saying Func<T> can make instantiation dynamic -> https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/funct-dynamic-instantiation/
Is this a valid usage? or do you have an example where using Func<T> as Dependency makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

You can hook into Simple Injector's pipeline and add profiling, which allows you to spot which types are slow to create. Here's an extension method that you can use:

```cs
public struct ProfileData {
    public readonly ExpressionBuildingEventArgs Info;
    public readonly TimeSpan Elapsed;

    public ProfileData(ExpressionBuildingEventArgs info, TimeSpan elapsed) {
        this.Info = info;
        this.Elapsed = elapsed;
    }
}

static void EnableProfiling(Container container, List<ProfileData> profileLog) {
    container.ExpressionBuilding += (s, e) => {
        Func<Func<object>, object> profilingWrapper = creator => {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var instance = creator.Invoke();
            profileLog.Add(new ProfileData(e, watch.Elapsed));
            return instance;
        };

        Func<object> instanceCreator = 
            Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(e.Expression).Compile();

        e.Expression = Expression.Convert(
            Expression.Invoke(
                Expression.Constant(profilingWrapper),
                Expression.Constant(instanceCreator)),
            e.KnownImplementationType);
    };
}
```

And you can use this as follows:

```cs
var container = new Container();

// TODO: Your registrations here.

// Hook the profiler
List<ProfileData> profileLog = new List<ProfileData>(1000);

// Call this after all registrations.
EnableProfiling(container, profileLog);

// Trigger verification to allow everything to be precompiled.
container.Verify();

profileLog.Clear();

// Resolve a type:
container.GetInstance<AuditFacade>();

// Display resolve time in order of time.
var slowestFirst = profileLog.OrderByDescending(line => line.Elapsed);

foreach (var line in slowestFirst)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ms: {1}", 
        line.Info.KnownImplementationType.Name, 
        line.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

Do note that the shown times include the time it takes to resolve the dependencies, but this will probably allow you pretty easily what type causes the delay.

There are two important thing I want to note about the given code here:

1. This code will have severely negative impact on the performance of resolving object graphs, and
2. The code is **NOT** thread-safe.

**So don't use it in your production environment.**

Answer (score 0):

Everything you do has a cost associated with it. *Typically*, more constructor parameters that are resolved recursively take *longer* than fewer parameters. But *you* must decide if the cost is ok or too high.

In your case, will the 50 ms cause a bottleneck? are you only creating 1 instance or are you puking them out in a tight loop? Just comparing the 1 ms with 50 ms might cause you to condemn the slower one, but if the user cannot tell that 50 ms passed and it doesn't cause a problem elsewhere in your app, why run through hoops to make it faster if you don't know it'll ever be needed?